# JBoss Seam Excel and HTTPS

Tags: excel, https, seam

Consider the following test view using Seam's Excel library:

```
<e:workbook type="csv">
    <e:worksheet name="Export" >
        <e:cell value="1" row="0" column="0"/>
        <e:cell value="2" row="1" column="1"/>
    </e:worksheet>
</e:workbook>
```

I'd like to secure parameters to a more complicated version via HTTPS.  The unsecure view generates the file fine.  When I change the scheme to "https" in view.page.xml, instead of my csv file, the browser is redirected to http://localhost/seam/docstore/document.seam with the conversation id in the query string. Other pages secured using https (e.g. login) are working fine.

Any suggestions on resolving or better diagnosing the problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to your security constraints settings in web.xml.  Take a look [here](http://seamframework.org/Community/ExportToPdfOrExcelFromRichdataTable).
If excel is trying to access resources outside of the restricted area you won't be able to generate the file.